# How to generate models that have a variable whose data type is Currency(java.util) with Swagger Codegen

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

Is there a way to generate models that have a variable whose data type is Currency(java.util) with Swagger Codegen?

Note: I use Swagger Version 2.0 and Swagger Codegen Version 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `Currency` object in your spec and then use `--import-mappings` to avoid creating a model for it.

The (partial) spec:

```yml
definitions:
  Bill:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      category:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Currency"
  Currency:
    type: "object"
```

The command:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -l java -i MySpec.yaml --import-mappings Currency=java.util.Currency
```

Or if you are using Maven, add this to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<configOptions> 
  <import-mappings>Currency=java.util.Currency</import-mapping‌​s>
</configOptions>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realised that I forgot saying that I use maven. Based on your answer, I searched the way how I can do it with maven and found a solution. After your recommended code is added into "definitions", there is also another extra configuration code should be added into pom.xml to make swagger codegen work properly: <configOptions>
                                <import-mappings>Currency=java.util.Currency</import-mappings>
                            </configOptions>